# Generated pictures with Universal Images Loader do not scale

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, androidsvg

I am using android-svg and UniversalImageLoader for displaying svg pictures in a custom chess component. Though the chess component is a subclass of ImageView, I can't just use

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage()
```

as the picture does not fill the ImageView, but only a cell, and the cell dimension is computed at runtime.

I've tried to use the method loadImage

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage("assets://svg/red_x_cross.svg",
            new ImageSize(sizePx, sizePx), loadedCompleteListener);
```

But it is as if I did not passed the ImageSize object : all images kept their original sizes.

Here is the configuration process :

```
DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new     DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new     ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .memoryCacheSize(175 * 1024)
            .diskCacheSize(175 * 1024)
            .imageDecoder(new SvgDecoder())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayImageOptions)
            .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Here the SvgDecoder :

```
/**
 * Utility class in order to configure Universal Image Loader library.
 * Code from glide project sample
 */
public class SvgDecoder implements ImageDecoder {
    @Override
    public Bitmap decode(ImageDecodingInfo imageDecodingInfo) throws     IOException {
        InputStream is = imageDecodingInfo.getDownloader().getStream(
                imageDecodingInfo.getImageUri(),   imageDecodingInfo.getExtraForDownloader());

        SVG svg;
        try {
            svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(is);
        } catch (SVGParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
        PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
        // I think the problem is in this call parameters (getWidth/getHeight)
        // but what must I write instead ?
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(image);

        svg.renderToCanvas(imageCanvas);

        return image;
    }
}
```

All svg files I am using define a viewbox.

I think the problem comes from the SvgDecoder I copied-paste from the Glide library sample, but I don't know what should I write instead (where I put a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was quite good when I said that it is the responsibility of SvgDecoder class to set the image size. In fact I must

- extends the BaseImageDecoder class from UIL
- add the following line just after having built the bitmap (it will compute the final size for me)

  decodedBitmap = considerExactScaleAndOrientatiton(decodedBitmap, decodingInfo, 0, false);